# Can a user exclude a keyword in search results?

Tags: algolia

For example, could they type "-Adventure" if they want results without the word adventure to appear in their search results?

Answer (score 4):

Sure thing! You need to enable the [**advancedSyntax** feature](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/parameters/#advancedsyntax) and then the `-` in front of words will be interpreted as a `NOT`.

```
index.search('Crazy -Adventure', { advancedSyntax: true }).then(...);
```

Will search all objects with `Crazy` and without `Adventure`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, now that I'm trying it, that doesn't seem to work. If I add the - then no results show up.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what's up here, but it's weird. You can do:

Crazy -Adventure

But you cannot do just:

-Adventure

If you just put the negative query it returns zero results. But you can do a negative query to filter out other stuff. 

Anybody know if there is a way to allow for a negative assertion on the whole catalog?

Comment: Ah yes indeed, you cannot "drive" the query with a negative word. This works with facet filters, just prepend a "-" to the value `filters: "myfacet:-myvalue"`.